# Vue3 homepage bug after build

Tags: vue.js, build, vuejs3, vue-router, router

I'm starting on VueJs3 and I created a small site project, it is composed of 3 pages (Home, Menu and contact). The project works perfectly on my development server, the app starts without problems, and when loading, I arrive on my Home page, which is defined in my routes.

The bug comes when I try to build my project, the compilation goes without problems, but when I launch the app, I arrive on an empty page, and I have to click on my "Home" link (or another) to see the content.

Does anyone have any idea what my bug is?

- Here is my router file

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
 
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [ 
    {
      path: '',
      name: 'Accueil',
      component: () => import('../views/HomeView.vue'),
    },
    {
      path: '/menu',
      name: 'Carte',
      component: () => import('../views/MenuView.vue'),
    }
  ]
})
 
export default router
```

I tried different way to set the site base route (`' '`, `'/'`) but none worked.

Each time, when I test the build version, the app launches, but the home page does not appear directly, I have to click on the router link to go there

However, on the dev version, no problems, the home page arrives directl.

- Here is my `app.vue`:

```html
<script>
import { RouterView } from 'vue-router';
import Header from './components/Header.vue';
import Footer from './components/Footer.vue';
 
export default{
  components:{ ... },
  data(){
    return{ ... }
  }, 
}
 
</script>
 
<template>
  <Header/> 
  <main>
    <RouterView/>
 </main> 
 <Footer/>   
</template>
```

Comment: Any error in your bash console? Browser console? Do you see something interesting in the Vue devtools (routes tab)? Try to use aliases `@` or  `~` rather than relative paths `../..` (or alike) for your `.vue` files. Do you maybe have a public github repo?

Comment: @kissu thank you for your answer, I don't have any error that comes out in my console, or in the plugins. you can find my project on https://github.com/Juli3n-dotcom/Vuejs-Jin-SushiStore.git

Comment: No build issues on the project that you shared. Do you properly run `npm run build && npm run preview`? Check the warnings in the shell console + make use of some ESlint + Prettier btw.

Comment: @kissu, my build works well, and I have no error, do you have the HomeView route that is displayed directly when you load the build project? or do you have a black page with only the header and the footer? because it is the result that I have, and which poses problem

Comment: When I'm in the `Jin` directory, I do run `npm run build && npm run preview`, then click on the given `http://localhost:4173/` link and it works perfectly with the page displayed, without any kind of issue.